# Expand Tableviewcell revealing labels at the bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When you select a tableviewcell it expands from 44 pixels to 100 pixels and when you deselect it will contract to 44 pixels again.

In the storyboard i've customized my cell to be 100pixels as standard and added 3 labels. one at the top and two at the bottom (the 2 labels at the bottom should not be visible and hide at the bottom).

When i run my app every cell will get the height of 44 pixels. The bottom two labels are visible at the correct x-coordinates but above every other cells.
like this:

[image: This is whats happening to my cells]

in viewDidLoad:

```
self.expandedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:1];
```

And the methods:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Compares the index path for the current cell to the index path stored in the expanded
    // index path variable. If the two match, return a height of 100 points, otherwise return
    // a height of 44 points.

    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        return 100.0; // Expanded height
    }
    return 44.0; // Normal height
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    UILabel *DateName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100100];
    DateName.text = _objects[indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];

if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
    self.expandedIndexPath = nil;
} else {
    self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;
}

[tableView endUpdates];
}
```

How can i hide the labels until the cells are expanded to 100 pixels?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: A question is a sentence that ends with `?`.

Comment: I've edited my question with a `?` master.

Comment: You can set the labels to `hidden`: `myLabel.hidden = YES;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cell to `clipToBounds = YES;`